# Return the object associated with the name

Tags: .net, vb.net, activator, createinstance

I'm connecting my program to some external code.  I'm setting it up so that the external code can instance objects and I've come across a problem.  I've created this function here:

```
Public Function InstanceOf(ByVal typename As String) As Object
    Dim theType As Type = Type.GetType(typename)
    If theType IsNot Nothing Then
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(theType)
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I'm trying to create a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object.  For what ever reason though, it always return `Nothing` instead of the object.  Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm doing this in VB.net so all .net responses are accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully through [the documentation of `Type.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), specifically, this part:

> If *typeName* includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll, in that order. If *typeName* is fully qualified with the partial or complete assembly name, this method searches in the specified assembly. If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required.

Since [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) is in System.dll (not Mscorlib.dll), you need to use the fully qualified name. Assuming you're using .Net 4.0, that would be:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

If you don't want to work with fully qualified names, you can go through all loaded assemblies and try to get the type using `Assembly.GetType()`.

Comment: How can I determine the fully qualified name for everything?  (i.e. how did you come up with that name?)

Comment: If you can access the type, then something like `typeof(Process).AssemblyQualifiedName` will return it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this for creating your Objects.

I defined a local class and also used your process example.

```
Public Class Entry
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim theName As String
        Dim t As Type = GetType(AppleTree)
        theName = t.FullName
        Setup.InstanceOf(theName)

        t = GetType(Process)

        theName = t.FullName & ", " & GetType(Process).Assembly.FullName


        Setup.InstanceOf(theName)

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Setup
    Shared function InstanceOf(typename As String) as object 
        Debug.Print(typename)
        Dim theType As Type = Type.GetType(typename)
        If theType IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(theType)
            '
            Debug.Print(o.GetType.ToString)
            return o
        End If
        return nothing 
    End function
End Class

Public Class AppleTree
    Public Sub New()
        Debug.Print("Apple Tree Created")
    End Sub
End Class
```